# Open and split a 4 channel RGB picture

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, rgb

How can I split an 4 channel rgb pic in qgis? With the value tool I can see 4 channel. I tried to use the RGB to PCT tool but I always get an error (File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin\pct2rgb.py", line 125, in 
ct_size = ct.GetCount() 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetCount' )

Comment: Now I just have a tiff with one band, and want to render this image using pct2rgb.py, but it also alert the same problem. How should I fix it? many thx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gdal_translate is able to extract single bands:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 in.tif out1.tif
gdal_translate -b 2 in.tif out2.tif
gdal_translate -b 3 in.tif out3.tif
gdal_translate -b 4 in.tif out4.tif
```

`Raster -> Conversion -> Translate` will create a gdal_translate command line, which you can edit to specify the band you want.

This also works with multiple `-b` flags:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 in.tif out.tif
```

This will produce an `out.tif` with three channels.